# RegionIntersection not returning what I expected

Tags: regions, inequalities

Consider the following implicit region defined on one variable

```
reg = {x > 0 && x < 0}
```

If I `Reduce` this system, I obviously get

```
Reduce[reg]
```

> `False`

However, If I use

```
RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[reg, {x}]]
```

I expect to get `EmptyRegion[]`, instead I get the output

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && x < 0, {x}]
> ```

Why does `RegionIntersection` not return `EmptyRegion[]`?

Comment: A simpler example (MWE): `RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[C11 > 0 && C11 < 0, {C11}]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. So, why it is not returning `EmptyRegion[]`? Are my expectations wrong?

Comment: Try `DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[reg, {C11}]]` -- I suppose regions are closed (i.e. boundaries are added).  I don't know for sure though.

Comment: `RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[C11 > 0 && C11 < 0, {C11}]] //ArcLength` evaluates to zero!

Comment: Reply to comment: If I knew why, I'd answer.  You could simplify the question, though, by editing to the question to show a ["minimal working code example"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am going to edit it

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for the tip, but it is only effective for one-dimensional regions (I have a code working with multi-variate regions). I need to understand why RegionIntersection is not returning EmptyRegion[].

Comment: `RegionDimension` yields `-Infinity`, which is consistent with `EmptyRegion[1]` and not with a single `Point` (which is what `DiscretizeRegion` returns). -- *Update*: `RegionIntersection[reg, reg]` fails but `RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[C11 > 0 && C11 < 0, {C11}], 
 ImplicitRegion[C11 < 0 && C11 > 0, {C11}]]` returns `EmptyRegion[1]`...Hmm, I suspect `RegionIntersection[r]` does nothing in all cases, perhaps.

Comment: Maybe this helps: `RegionIntersection[reg, ImplicitRegion[-Infinity < x < Infinity, {x}]]`

Comment: Maybe this helps: `MapAt[Simplify, ImplicitRegion[reg, {C11}], 1]`  -- in previous comment, I meant `reg` to be wrapped in `ImplicitRegion[..]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Region-combination functions such as `RegionIntersection` call [`BooleanRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion.html) to compute the result.  For instance,
`RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2,…]` is equivalent to `BooleanRegion[And, {reg1, reg2,…}]`

In turn, `BooleanRegion` seems to apply some basic logic to eliminate unnecessary computation. The following and their equivalent `RegionIntersection` calls return `region` without inspecting, simplifying, or otherwise altering `region`:

```
BooleanRegion[And, {region}]
BooleanRegion[And, {region, region}]  (* DeleteDuplicates[] is used to remove copies *)
BooleanRegion[And, {region, FullRegion[n]}]  (* where n is the dimension of region *)
```

Possible workarounds include intersecting `region` with a region distinct from `region` and `FullRegion[n]` that covers `region`.  Simply specifying a full region as an `ImplicitRegion` or changing the variables in `region` suffice.  Unfortunately `Simplify[ImplicitRegion[..]]` does nothing. In this case, if we apply `Simplify` or `Reduce` to the first argument gets around this.

```
ireg = ImplicitRegion[x < 0 && x > 0, {x}]
yreg = ireg /. x -> y  (* change variable *)
fullreg = ImplicitRegion[-Infinity < x < Infinity, {x}] (* a disguised full region *)
(*
  ImplicitRegion[x < 0 && x > 0, {x}]
  ImplicitRegion[y < 0 && y > 0, {y}]
  ImplicitRegion[-∞ < x < ∞, {x}]
*)

RegionIntersection[ireg, yreg]
RegionIntersection[ireg, fullreg]
(*
  EmptyRegion[1]
  EmptyRegion[1]
*)
```

Simplification:

```
MapAt[Simplify, ireg, 1]
MapAt[Reduce, ireg, 1]
(*
  EmptyRegion[1]
  EmptyRegion[1]
*)
```

It seems *Mathematica* is missing a `RegionSimplify` or `RegionReduce` function.  At least, I didn't find one.

Answer (score -1):

$\underline{\mathbf{UPDATE}}$

```
Q = ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && x < 0, {x}];
Q = If[RegionDimension[Q] == -\[Infinity], EmptyRegion[1]]
```

returns:

```
EmptyRegion[1]
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question....and some of this answer was noted in the comments.

Comment: The region of intersection is the empty region, which is one of the OP's points.  The question is how to get it to simplify to it. It's okay to repeat from the comments, but usually the practice is to acknowledge the prior post(s).  -- Not sure why the downvotes here.